# Jqplot: Fill color between two lines

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, jqplot

I am using `fillBetween` property of [Jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) to fill the area between to series with the specified color:

```
fillBetween: {
    // series1: Required, if missing won't fill.
    series1: 0,
    // series2: Required, if  missing won't fill.
    series2: 1,
    // color: Optional, defaults to fillColor of series1.
    color: "rgba(227, 167, 111, 0.7)",
    baseSeries: 0,
    // fill:  Optional, defaults to true.  False to turn off fill.  
    fill: true
}
```

As per the example above, it fill the area between series 0 and series 1 with the color specified.

I want to fill the area between 0 and 1, 2 and 3 ,and 4 and 5 series. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You may find something interesting [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/area.html)

Comment: @AnthonyLeGovic - I believe he'd like multiple fills between two lines, and not between a line and the axis as with the example you provided.  I have the same question as him, TBH.  I can't figure out how to do this in JQPlot. IE: this example http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/fillBetweenLines.html but with multiple fill areas

Comment: Have you try to specify several "fillBetween" blocks? I didn't try this and not sure of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the fix for this problem:
[Bitbucket pull request for jqplot](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/pull-request/51/changes-made-to-incorporate-an-array-of/diff)

I have committed the change into the main Jqplot repo to get merged into the next release.
Feel free to use my fix if you need it.